# Linked list add method not working as expected

Tags: java, pointers, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

So i am trying to solve a problem that involves adding objects to a linked list. I have been on this problem since morning and so far i have not got the exact output yet.

My program is basically adding patients to a linked list according to two criteria, `severity` and `arrival`.
I want to add patients from highest to lowest using `severity`. And if they do have the same severity then i want to store them according to arrival in ascending order. So for instance,

> Patient 1, arrival 2, severity 3
>
> Patient 2, arrival 3, severity 3

Or if they have different severity then like this:

> Patient 1, arrival 2, severity 2
>
> Patient 2, arrival 1, severity 1

In short `severity` has to be in descending order and **if the severity is the same** then store them in ascending order according to `arrival`.

What i have tried so far is this, this method is in the `patient` class:

```
public boolean compareSeverity(Patient other) {
 boolean result = false;
 if(other.severity > severity) {
  result = true;
 } else if(other.severity == severity) {
    if(other.arrival > arrival) {
     result = true;
    } else {
      result = false;
    }
  } else {
    result = false;
  }
  return result;
 }
```

And this is how i coded my `add` method for the `linked list` class.

```
public void add(String name, int severity) {
 lastArrival++;
 Patient patient = new Patient(name, lastArrival, severity);
 PatientNode current, previous;
 current = head;
 previous = null;
 if(head == null) {
  head = current = new PatientNode(patient, head);
  size++;
 } else {
   while(current!=null) {
    //previous = current;
    if(current.data.compareSeverity(patient)) {
     PatientNode n = new PatientNode(patient,current);
     size++;
     if(previous!=null) {
      previous.next = n;
      }
      return;
     }
     previous = current;
     current = current.next;
    }
  }
 }
```

However when i try to run my program it just shows only one patient.

I have been tinkering with my method from the morning and this is what i have got so far. Maybe i need a new set of eyes because right now i am going nowhere with this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[The output that i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ins7n.png)

**Edit 2**

The list is printing out completely but the it is not executing the criteria that if the severity is the same then store the patients in ascending order.

[New Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M5lp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the pointer from previous to n, but you never set the pointer from n to next.   You are only making one of the two links you need in a linked list.

```
if(current.data.compareSeverity(patient)) {
    PatientNode nextHolder = current.next;
    PatientNode n = new PatientNode(patient,current);
    size++;
    n.next = current;   //this line forgotten??
    if(previous==null) {
        head = n;
    }
    else {
        previous.next = n;
    }
    return;
}


previous = current;
current = current.next;
```

You also need to handle the case where the new patent is first in the list, and the head variable needs to be updated.

Comment: Am i not handling the first patient through the `if(head==null)` statement?

Comment: I just ran the program but it still shows only one patient. It seems like it is losing the nodes.

Comment: I just added in the proper correction for the case that the NEW patient is the first in the list.  In that case, you need to make the head variable point to the new record.  If your test was not dong this, then you might end up with never updating the head, and never seeing anything but the first one you put in.

Comment: Well that worked as far as the output was concerned but the code seems to be not storing the patients when their **severity is the same** in ascending order. I have added a new output that kind of shows what i am talking about.